# Could we have a "decent" statistics of which links the users visited from our user's profile?

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, profile-page, hyperlinks

I'm just curious, but I would like to know which links were visited most in my user's profile (I know, I have only one right now :) Hover on any link does nothing and I bet you collect this information :P

So, could we display how many users "clicked" the link on a user's profile when hovering a certain link (show a hint how many users clicked a certain link)?

Comment: Yeah, I'm pretty sure we *don't* collect this data.

Comment: @Shog9, sad to hear that then :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're talking about links *to* your profile, that's counted right on the profile itself: https://stackoverflow.com/users/8041231/victoria?tab=profile - right-hand side, labeled "profile views" with a creepy hieroglyphic next to it.

If you're talking about links to various sub-sections of your profile, we track some of these but only in aggregate; I can tell you how many people clicked "next badge" or "next privilege", but not how many times *you* clicked those links. I could scrape the logs and make an educated guess, but it'd take literally days to do that and I'm not that curious.

If you're talking about links within your bio text... We don't track those at all. If you own the site you're linking to, you could add some sort of unique querystring I guess.

Comment: I was talking about links within my bio text. Pity. Thank you for the answer! (how I wish all the SW companies have support as you) :)